# How to increase the size of the Performance Analytics widget in Service Now?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, servicenow, highcharts-ng

I am new to ServiceNow Portal and trying to increase the size of the Gauge in the Performance Analytics widget. The top two gauges are from Report widget. It looks fit with the column. But the bottom widget is so small. How can I increase the size?

[image]

Widget Html

```
<div class="pa-widget-service-portal__parent-container">
<div class="pa-widget-service-portal" role="group">
    <h2 class="title-container "
        id="{{'title-' + c.titleId}}"
        ng-class="{ show: c.showTitle }">
        {{::c.title}}
    </h2>
    <div class="initial-message-container" ng-class="{ show: c.initialMessageVisible }">
        {{::c.initialMessage}}
    </div>
    <div class="react-component" ng-if="c.reactComponent">
        <pa-react-wrapper
            type="{{::c.widgetRoute}}"
            uuid="{{::c.uuid}}"
            widget-id="{{::c.widgetId}}"
            lang={{::c.lang}}
            dow={{::c.dow}}
            visualization={{::c.visualization}}
            insights-Enabled={{::c.insightsEnabled}}
            text-cutoff-value={{::c.cutoffValue}}
            text-cutoff-type={{::c.cutoffType}}
            text-cutoff-condition={{::c.cutoffCondition}}
            text-limit={{::c.textLimit}}
            text-default-field={{::c.defaultField}}
            text-words-trendline-limit={{::c.textWordsInTrendline}}>
        </pa-react-wrapper>
    </div>
</div>
```

Widget Client Script

```
function paSPClientController($compile, $element, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
/* widget controller */
var c = this;

// Initial message
c.initialMessageVisible = !Boolean(c.options.widget_id);
c.initialMessage = c.data.i18n.initialMessage;

// Title
c.title = '';
c.showTitle = (c.options.show_title && c.options.show_title !== 'false');
if (c.options.widget_parameters) {
    var widgetParameters = JSON.parse(c.options.widget_parameters);
    if (typeof widgetParameters.widget_id === 'object')
        c.title = widgetParameters.widget_id.displayValue;
}

//PA messages
if (!top.SNC.PA.msg || $.isEmptyObject(top.SNC.PA.msg)) {
    top.SNC.PA.msg = JSON.parse(c.data.i18n.paMsgs);
}

var httpOptions = {
    url: 'angular.do',
    params: {
        sysparm_type: 'pa_widget',
        type: 'getwidgetserviceportal',
        widget: c.options.widget_id
    }
};
$http(httpOptions, true).then(function afterResponse(result) {
    if (!result.data.type || !result.data.sys_id)
        return;
    
    c.initialMessageVisible = false;
    if (c.showTitle)
        c.titleId = result.data.sys_id;
    
    var compiledWidget;
    if (isReactWidget(result.data.type, result.data.newVisualizationEnabled)) {
        // Text Analytics Widget is in React
        c.widgetId = result.data.sys_id;
        c.uuid = result.data.uuid;
        c.reactComponent = true;
        c.lang = c.data.language;
        c.dow = c.data.dow;
        c.cutoffValue = result.data.text_cut_off_value;
        c.cutoffType = result.data.text_cut_off_type;
        c.cutoffCondition = result.data.text_cut_off_condition;
        c.defaultField = result.data.text_default_field;
        c.textLimit = result.data.text_limit;
        c.visualization = result.data.visualization;
        c.textWordsInTrendline = result.data.text_words_in_trendline;
        c.type = result.data.type;
        c.insightsEnabled = result.data.insightsEnabled;
        switch(c.type) {
            case 'text': c.widgetRoute = '/widgets/text-analytics'; break;
            case 'insight': c.widgetRoute = '/widgets/insights'; break;
            case 'time': c.widgetRoute = '/widgets/time-series'; break;
            case 'score': c.widgetRoute = '/widgets/single-score'; break;
            default: c.widgetRoute = '/widgets/text-analytics'; break;
        }
        
        $timeout(function afterAngularRender() {
            var element = angular.element('pa-react-wrapper', $element).get(0);
            window.servicePortalPaUIWidget.render(element);
        });
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function onAngularDestroy() {
            var element = angular.element('pa-react-wrapper', $element).get(0);
            window.servicePortalPaUIWidget.destroy(element);
        });
    } else {
        // Will be removed when we switch all widgets to react
        compiledWidget = $compile('<div class="pa-widget-' + result.data.type + '" widget="' + result.data.sys_id + '"></div>')($scope);
        angular.element('.pa-widget-service-portal', $element).append(compiledWidget);
    }
});

function isReactWidget(type, newVisualizationEnabled) {
    var reactWidgetTypes = ['text', 'insight'];
    if (newVisualizationEnabled) {
        reactWidgetTypes.push('time');
        reactWidgetTypes.push('score');
    }
    return reactWidgetTypes.indexOf(type) != -1;
}}
```

Widget Server Script

```
(function() {
/* populate the 'data' object */
data.i18n = {
    initialMessage: gs.getMessage('Please select a widget'),
    paMsgs: SNC.PAUtils.getMessages()
};
data.language = gs.getSession().getLanguage();
data.dow = gs.getProperty('glide.ui.date_format.first_day_of_week', 1);
 })();
```

I tried with the Highchart Configuration code, but no change.

```
var gaugeOptions = {
chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge'
},

title: null,

pane: {
    center: ['50%', '85%'],
    size: '140%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
    }
} }
```

Comment: Could you explain the correlation between Highcharts and ServiceNow Portal? How this chart config should impact those charts and how the Highcharts chart is initialized?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I have updated with Client Script and Server Script.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel When I inspect the elements I can understand that its from Highchart Library. No idea How this initialized. Its a default Servicenow Widget.

Comment: I think that you should contact the Servicenow support in this case.